# Special Foundation framework responsive grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm using version 4.2.1 of Zurb's Foundation framework and I'm trying to conditionally drop boxes onto a new row for `small` devices. See this figure:

[image: A comparison picture showing four boxes side-by-side on a computer and the four boxes in two rows on a smaller phone.]

I found a way to make this work, but my method breaks when the boxes have non-uniform heights. My semi-working code currently looks like [this](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/svtLF).

But when I change the size of some of the boxes, it breaks like [this](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/KwoHs).

At worst, I can probably use use `min-height` and `max-height` to make sure the boxes stay the same size?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a very simple solution. Use the **block grid** instead of the normal grid as follows:

```
  <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
    <li style="outline:solid black 1px;">Test</li>
    <li style="outline:solid black 1px;">Test</li>
    <li style="outline:solid black 1px;">Test</li>
    <li style="outline:solid black 1px;">Test</li>
  </ul>
```

Hopefully that helps someone.